# como comparar un elemento en una lista Haskell

Tags: haskell

Estaba tratando de hacer una función que compare un elemento dado con una lista y si el elemento esta el la lista regrese un Booleano.

al compilarlo me lanza este error y no entiendo a que se refiere.
apreciaria mucho su ayuda...

```
  Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
  • In the second argument of ‘(/=)’, namely ‘xs’
  In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘n /= xs’
  In the expression: n /= x && n /= xs
• Relevant bindings include
    n :: a (bound at Listas.hs:22:17)
    xs :: [a] (bound at Listas.hs:22:13)
    x :: a (bound at Listas.hs:22:11)
    elemento :: [a] -> a -> Bool (bound at Listas.hs:21:1)
    |
 22 | elemento (x:xs) n = if n /= x && n /= xs then False else True
```

este es el código:

```
 elemento :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
 elemento [] a = error "no hay elementos en la lista"
 elemento (x:xs) n = if n /= x && n /= xs then False else True
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas Pedro, te dejo un ejemplo de búsqueda basado en tu código que debería funcionar:

```
elemento :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool
elemento (x:xs) a = if a == x then True else elemento xs a
elemento [] a = False
```

Espero que te pueda ayudar. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

El error es algo confuso. Te dice que *no puede construir un tipo infinito*. Puede que no lo entiendas, pero en las siguientes líneas te indica que el problema está en `n /= xs`. Estás comparando un elemento de tipo `a` con una lista de elementos de tipo `a`, lo que viene a definir el tipo `a` como de *tipo recursivo infinito*, algo imposible de implementar.

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería usando *recursividad*:

```
elemento :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool
elemento [] _ = False
elemento (x:xs) a | x == a    = True
                  | otherwise = elemento xs a
```

Hay otros modos, por ejemplo con *compresión de listas*:

```
elemento :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool
elemento xs a = or [x==a | x <- xs]
```

Supongo que estás empezando con haskell. Este tipo de chequeos se pueden hacer directamente con la función `elem` que se carga en el `Prelude`, por lo que está disponible directamente. Únicamente habría que invertir los argumentos:

```
elemento :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool
elemento = flip elem
```